# Grails hasMany relationship list with null and missing entries

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am experiencing the following issue with a hasMany (1-M) relationship when using Grails / Terracotta. I have the following domain models (pseudocode):

```
User {
    String username

    List languages

    static hasMany = [ languages: Language ]

    static mapping = {
        cache true
        languages cache: true, cascade: "all-delete-orphan", lazy: true
    }
}

Language {

    String name

    static belongsTo = [user: User]
}
```

This is being returned as JSON using a marshaller registered in BootStrap.groovy:

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(User) {
    def returnArray = [:]
    returnArray['id'] = it.id
    returnArray['username']
    returnArray['languages'] = it.languages
}


JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Language) {
        def returnArray = [:]
        returnArray['id'] = it.id
        returnArray['name'] = it.name
}
```

The issue that we encountering is that with the cache (Terracotta) we are seeing users who have multiple languages in the database are being in the front end with only one language. The JSON being returned looks like:

```
{
 id: 1
 username: "Test",
 languages: [
     null,
    {"id": 1089,name: "French"}
 ]
}
```

In this example, the user had three languages in the database (all with the correct index set for the list) yet in the application we see the above. Clearing the cache on restart and the issue goes away but it then happens for other users in a pattern I have not been able to replicate.

The question is under what circumstances something like this might happen, where the list is out of sequence or missing entries for a hasMany relationship.

It's a common use case to search for users by language. I'm wondering if during this search, where an alias is used in the criteria query might be only loading the matching language in the list and caching this?

I have not been able to reproduce the behavior though in a dev or qa environment.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if it's related to the same problem I'm having here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29213809/why-is-grails-hasmany-list-size-wrong

Comment: It certainly seems related. I have come across situations like yours before when children are not removed properly from the parent i.e. the child.delete() is called but never removed from the parent. If you have a belongsTo in the child domain class, there is no foreign key to prevent this in the DB and the idx can be out of order. In my case the idx is in order and values are in the DB but they are not loaded into memory in some scenarios.

Comment: have same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011627/null-in-hasmany-assosiation-list-after-removing-item . Any idea, how to ignore null items during loading from DB?