# Why is Grails hasMany List size wrong?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain object Parent that has a hasMany relationship implemented as a List.  I am getting an incorrect size of List returned and I don't know why:

```
class Parent {
    List children

    static hasMany = [children : Child, otherHasMany : SomeOtherChildClass]

    static mapping = {
        children lazy: false
    }
}

def parent = Parent.get(someId) // parent is returned as a result of a query
def numChildren = parent.children.size()
```

I am getting a lot of null values interspersed amongst the correct Children within the children List.

i.e.

```
parent.children.each {
    println it
}
```

gives:

```
Child 1
NULL
Child2
NULL
Child3
Child4
...  // seemingly random order of NULLs interspersed between correct values, but there never appear to be 2 NULLs in a row
```

In my case, the `size()` call returns 71 Children, yet there are only 51 Children that should be in the Parent.

When I execute an SQL query I get the correct number of Children:

```
SELECT count(*)  from CHILDREN where parent_id = someId
51
```

When I turn on SQL logging and check to see the query that Hibernate is executing, I get the same correct answer (51).

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: you should find out, what those null are.  is it the result from the it.tostring() or is it itself null

Comment: Not sure, but check if you may are doing a LEFT OUTTER Join. You could enable Hibernate SQL logging with `debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'` in the log4j closure of the config.

Comment: Do I understand you get 20 NULLs in the output of the children.each closure?

Comment: The problem is that there are null objects in the hasMany List. `size()` returns 71, not 51.  It's not the `toString()` that's the issue.  There isn't a `LEFT OUTER` join that I can see, it appears to just be a query similar to `SELECT *  from CHILDREN where parent_id = someId` that Hibernate creates.

Comment: have same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011627/null-in-hasmany-assosiation-list-after-removing-item . Any idea, how to ignore null items during loading from DB?

Answer (score 3):

When a domain is created like you have created

```
class Parent {
    List children
    static hasMany = [children : Child]
}
```

then to make this work, grails add the `children_idx` column to the `Child` table. The values in this column are important because grails use this for making list (placing instance in order). The first record will have its value set to `0`, the next `1`, and so forth. And **if this sequence is broken, then you got null in the list**.

This may be the issue.

To avoid breaking the sequence, make sure you remove the associated object from its owner when deleting the associated object.

Ref [Collections in GORM](https://maxkorytko.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/collections-in-gorm/)

Comment: Thanks very much, I already have a children_idx and that suggestion seems to match where the nulls are.  However, I haven't deleted any of the children, so I'm not sure why the sequencing is out.  Do you have any suggestions as to why this might be the case please?

Comment: Then may be issue is in adding children in Parent domain. Can you post your code where you adding children in Parent doamin? And your grails version.

Comment: Child is added using `def child = new Child(); parent.addToChildren(child); parent.save();`.  The are multiple threads doing this, could this be the issue?  Grails version is 2.4.3.

Comment: In my project, I also have this type of domains (grails v2.3.9). And `addToChildren` itself call `parent.save()` (don't know the reason), and If I explicitly doing `parent.save()` then `parent.children` gives me list with some null values. So I have removed explicit save. May be same issue with you. I will try to reproduce this issue with v2.4.3 and update you after my work.

Comment: I tried with grails v2.4.4 and it is working fine. May be some other reason for this sequence broken.