# Null in hasMany assosiation list after removing item

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

There is domain object:

```
 class Book {
      List<Picture> pictures
      static hasMany = [pictures:Picture]
      static mapping = {
        pictures lazy: false, cache: 'nonstrict-read-write'
      }
    }
```

Sometimes, after deleting pictures from list by code it produce null item in pictures list.

```
..
book.refresh()
def pic = Picture.get(params.id)
subject.removeFromPictures(pic)
subject.save()
```

It looks like, GORM not update idx field in assosiation table.
I can't reproduce it, but I got few times it on production server

In my opinion, it can be problem of second level cache and concurent modification. How to prevent it?

Grails 2.4.5
MariaDB

Comment: I looks like a GORM gotcha. Posts 2 and 3 in GORM gotchas series could be usefull, http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/, http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/28/gorm-gotchas-part-3/

Comment: Very interesting articles, but nothing related to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem can depend on the cascade delete behaviour you set on the class.
First of all, after calling

```
subject.removeFromPictures(pic)
subject.save()
```

You have to call.

```
pic.delete()
```

But if the problem persist, you can use GORM events so in your class you can add:

```
class Book {
...
...
def beforeUpdate(){
checkNulls()
}

def beforeValidate(){
checkNulls()
}

def checkNulls(){
pictures?.removeAll(null)
}
```

Ref: [GORM Events](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping)

Comment: By the logic of app, I can't remove picture entity. Now I have something like method checkNulls in my code, but it looks ugly